# Can someone help me better understand Cross Site Scripting Policy

Tags: javascript, html, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to better understand Cross Site Scripting and lets use:

http://api.beatport.com/crossdomain.xml as the example.

The XML lists that **all** domains are allowed access. However when I make the request from within my HTML page (or from within the console) it will **fail** with an error similar to:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.beatport.com/catalog/tracks. Origin <mydomain> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What I find weird though, is if I put the request in the address bar of my browser, the request goes through.

Can someone please explain what is going on and what I need to do to fix this because clearly the API allows access from any domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` doesn't look at `crossdomain.xml`, it looks at `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as mentioned in the error message.

So the server needs to send a header like this:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

If they don't send that header (`http://api.beatport.com/catalog/tracks` doesn't), it will be denied.

Comment: Is there anyways around it? (Modifying header or however it works for Extensions?)

Comment: @Setheron do you mean chrome extensions? then you can do this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: Well, I am injecting my script into their HTML page because I need access to their *same* jQuery instance so that I can hook into their Global ajax events. Is there a way to hook into all jQuery instances otherwise?

Comment: @Setheron if you have your own extension or greasemonkey you can make requests where you please, if you are just injecting js somewhere then there is nothing you can do about it except use flash as a "proxy"... see http://flxhr.flensed.com/